# How to develop a desktop application or exe file for the web app developed in PHP,so that the customer can access it when there is no internet

Tags: php, desktop-application, exe

We have a web-application(Loyalty platform for restaurants) developed in PHP. But most of these merchants dont have internet connection all the time. So, is there way to convert only merchant module into a desktop application so that merchant works stand alone and it syncs to web application whenever there is an internet connection.

Comment: At first this sounded so wrong to me, but then I though of HTML5 and offline content, and even though I know PHP y server-side, It would be nice to see what options people tells you besides "it can't be done, PHP is web and server-side"

Answer (score 3):

Yes it is possible ,but not like a wizard job.

If you know only PHP than you can use [Titanium](http://www.appcelerator.com/) ,and deploy Desktop App's. 
You can use a local database ,an XML ,jSON or SQLite and on the first connection with internet you can clear the local database and update the Remote one.

Comment: Cool, throw in some HTML5 and "offline content", I'd really like to see this can be done!

Comment: I still doubt HTML and offline content can be used for application which are completely dependent on offline content :) .. for quick simple apps they are okay. Just my thought.

Comment: @Shoban well the best solution could be a .NET Application with Entity Framework ,but the OP asked with PHP tag ,so we get a PHP Solution .

Comment: Yes.. that was going to be my suggestion too.

Comment: @Shoban I haven't really worked with HTML5 offline-content, that's why I want to have my mind blown and see something like: "Sure, it's easy! Just use X  app for the PHP Desktop App and let it access the data through offline content"

Comment: I haven't looked at the documentation in-depth, but it seems to me that using Titanium will still require major amounts of rearchitecting...

Answer (score 2):

I am working on a similar project and in my case I am following the below aproach.

1. Web Application is PHP and MySQL
2. Desktop Application is .net Application using SQL Lite
3. Windows Service checks for internet connection and syncs db in the background

In my case, my users can go offline for days or weeks and data was critical for me and I felt HTML 5 offline content was not the best option for this.

Answer (score 0):

No. Designing a desktop PHP app is *very* different from designing a web PHP app and will require major amounts of rearchitecting.

Now having said that, it *is* possible to deploy a web server to the client's machine and have it run a web PHP app there. It will still require some rearchitecting to get the sync working though.

Comment: So, It CAN be done, the thing is "HOW" it's done and if its viable. Maybe having WAMP around in every laptop it's not a practical solution, but it's a way. I'd like to see more from the other answer

Comment: It doesn't have to be a full WAMP stack; there are many lighter web servers available if all you need is CGI access to PHP.

Answer (score 0):

Develop a desktop application in .net or Java what ever you are familiar with and use some database like SQLite to save the data locally. When ever the user goes to online you need to connect to your online database and sync the data.

If there is possibility that same data can be updated by different users, then you have to plan on handling the conflicting scenarios like if a data record is updated at both end which data should be used. If there is no possibility to concurrent update then simply you will have to upload your data when user goes online.